# Using custom commands in sections

Tags: nightwatch.js

Having a simple custom command like this (file pressTab.js):

```
exports.command = function() {
    this.keys(this.Keys.TAB);
    return this;
};
```

I am defining a section in a page and try to call this command from the section:

```
module.exports = {
    url: "...",
    commands: [{
        testCommandInSection: function(){
            this.section.testSection.callPressTab();
            return this;
        }
    }],
    sections: {
        testSection: {
            selector: ".mySectionCssSelector",
            commands: [{
                callPressTab: function() {
                    this.pressTab();
                    return this;
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

If I now use

```
myPage.testCommandInSection();
```

an error is thrown before starting the nightwatch queue:

```
Error while running testCommandInSection command: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

**But** this error does not show up, if I add a dummy parameter to the pressTab call:

```
            callPressTab: function() {
                this.pressTab("dummy");
                return this;
            }
```

**and** this doesn't happen, if I call this.pressTab() directly from the page, but not from the section. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with "`this`" object :

- In custom commands, "this" usually is browser
- In pageobject, it depends .

  *In your case, your first`this.section.testSection.callPressTab();` is your page object, and your second one `this.pressTab();` is your section object.

If you want to call custom commands with Browser object,  you should try "`this.api.YourCustomCommand`"

```
testSection: {
            selector: ".mySectionCssSelector",
            commands: [{
                callPressTab: function() {
                    this.api.pressTab();
                    return this;
                }
            }]
        }
```